# cross compiling gstreamer fails: x86-64 -> ARMv6 32-bit

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling, gstreamer

I am trying to build a project on an x86_64 (linux)system for an RPi 1. I have a working tool chain - I have built a small program and run it on the RPi ("Hello World").

The project that I am trying to build is ***gstreamer***
.

In the ***configure script***, I added the appropriate ***--host=***, and it finds all of the right tools and successfully completes. But then, when I make the project, 
I get the following errors:

```
    In file included from gsttracerutils.h:30:0,
                 from gst_private.h:68,
                 from gst.c:96:
../gst/gstutils.h: In function '__gst_slow_read64_be':
../gst/gstutils.h:111:61: error: left shift count >= width of type [-Werror=shift-count-overflow]
     (((guint##__size) (((const guint8 *) (__data))[__idx])) << (__shift))
                                                             ^
../gst/gstutils.h:164:36: note: in expansion of macro '_GST_GET'
 #define _GST_READ_UINT64_BE(data) (_GST_GET (data, 0, 64, 56) | \
                                    ^
../gst/gstutils.h:184:10: note: in expansion of macro '_GST_READ_UINT64_BE'
   return _GST_READ_UINT64_BE (data);
          ^
```

It seems (at least to me) like the compiler complaining about a 64bit type on a 32 bit cpu (which is right).

Is this a problem with the toolchain compiler? Or something else?

I originally built (successfully) gstreamer on the rpi itself. But since that took a very long time, and I need to be able to re-make the app, I wanted to build it on a fast system.

For clarification:
The build toolchain I am using is ***crosstool-ng***. 
I ran the configure command as:

```
./configure --disable-gtk-doc --disable-examples --disable-benchmarks --disable-gtk-doc-html --host=armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabihf
```

and from the configure log (config.log):

```
## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:3217: checking build system type
configure:3231: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:3251: checking host system type
configure:3264: result: armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabihf
configure:3284: checking target system type
configure:3297: result: armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabihf
configure:3343: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:3411: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:3422: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:3477: result: yes
configure:3536: checking for armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabihf-strip
configure:3552: found /nas/temp/build/rpi/tc/x-tools/armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabihf/bin/armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabihf-strip
configure:3563: result: armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabihf-strip
```

this shows the build system is x86_64, the host and the target are armv6(...).

The errors, as shown above, relate to macros that deal with 64 bit data.

I can take this identical project tree, run autogen.sh,configure.sh, and make on the rpi-1 itself (using the pignus version of gcc tools - pignus is a fedora 23 spin specifically for the rpi-1), and it completely builds successfully. I also built this project on, and for, the x86_64 system, which was also successful.

And, as mentioned at the beginning, I have built a simple program using the same toolchain - the "Hello World" program - and it compiled and linked successfully on the x86_64 system, and then ran successfully on the rpi.

So, again, my question is: could this be a problem/bug with the cross compiler toolchain, or perhaps something in the project source? Any suggestions on where to look, or what to try?

TIA

ken

Comment: Did you set `ARCH` and `CROSS_COMPILE`?

Comment: yes, both are set. Also, this if for armv6 processor (rpi-1), not v7 (rpi-2/3).

Comment: in configure.sh script: "--host=" sets the architectures, and the cross-compile flag (FWIW: --host=armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabihf"). And as mentioned, these values worked - eg, compiled a working app. Sorry, I thought that people knew what that configure option was for.

Comment: The ARMv7 thing was kinda my bad for not noting the "Rpi-1" thing (I don't think of them as "model 1"s, I just think of them as A/B/+/0, or the ARMv6 version) -- but it never hurts to explain relevant details of the context and obviously the cross-compiler is important here (the reason I assumed v7 is linux distros come stock with one, whereas using ct-ng etc is a step beyond).

Comment: ..Anyway, gnarly looking tangle of macros.  Obviously you don't want to bother changing anything, but there's the outside chance it is actually a corner case bug in gstreamer.  *You could try asking nicely for an opinion on their -devel mail list*: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/lists/ Actually looks like an answer just dropped in \O/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From unpicking [those macros](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/tree/gst/gstutils.h#n110), what the compiler is specifically complaining about is that shifting a value of type `guint64` left by 56 bits overflows the type, and is thus undefined.

Now, what that says to me is that you're picking up your *host machine's* glibconfig.h, where `guint64` must be a typedef of `unsigned long`, i.e. a 64 bit type on that machine, but 32 bits once you feed it into the 32-bit ARM compiler. On the Pi itself you probably have an appropriately-configured glibconfig.h where `guint64` is a typedef of `unsigned long long` instead, hence building natively works.

You need to point the build at the Pi's GLib headers and libraries rather than the host machine's (this compilation error is almost certainly just delaying an ultimate failure to link when the cross-linker finds x86 libraries and rejects them). I've no experience with GStreamer myself, so I can't say exactly how to do that, but according to [this mailing list post](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/GStreamer-ARM-cross-compilation-td4659980.html) I found, the correct approach would seem to involve overriding PKG_CONFIG_PATH.

Comment: yes, that is what I thought. macros were for 64 bit. as for glib, I can't seem to find it anywhere in my toolchain (crosstool-ng). from your mailing list link, it looked like I needed to cross-build glib  first. Does that sound right? as for PKG_CONFIG_PATH, within the toolchain, there are .pc files, so I can add that path onto PKG_CONFIG_PATH, I guess.

Comment: You shouldn't need to cross-build GLib yourself, especially as that might lead to version mismatches. Just mount/copy the Pi's filesystem onto the host machine and point at that - then you're building against the exact same things you'll run with (and you know it's all there already since the native build was fine).

Comment: Hey! That's a GREAT idea!. The problem I am having is exactly that - get the cross compiler to see the target environment and not the build's. Never thought about using the actual file system. And since, for the rpi, it is on an SD, just pop it into the build machine, say a few magic mount words, and voila! But I am still having a problem where the make process wants to use the build's paths (/usr/include, etc), and ignore what's been configured. Will try this one out and let you know. Thanks, @Notlikethat.

Comment: tried this. main problem I still have is that compiler picks up the build system's include files, instead of the target's. I have explicitly used --with-sysroot=<sd mount point>, --includedir=<sd mount point>/usr/include (and others). But the compiler uses up the build system's path first, before trying these explicit paths. Can I make `make` change that?

Comment: Yeah `--sysroot=` is good practice to save many headaches, but it only changes the default search paths, so won't take precedence over anything explicitly-provided. Well-behaved projects tend to give you control over external dependencies, e.g. `configure --with-libwidget=/path...`, `make LIBDOODAH=/path...`, and such. Some projects, on the other hand, are just bastards to cross-compile. Funnily enough, just today I spent longer hacking at a makefile trying to convince a cross-build to work than it ultimately took to boot a dev board, clone the thing onto that and build it natively.

Comment: Your answer about `--sysroot` was one that I had wondered about for awhile. Now I know. But I did find this specific problem. For some strange reason, `glib` needs its own specific set of flags, such as `includedirs` (eg, GLIB_FLAGS). Anyone notice that in the `configure --help`? I finally did and I got past the `glibXXX` not found errors. Now I am dealing with code full of stupid warnings (unused vars, signed vs. unsigned, etc.). Dangerous, but easiest to turn off all warnings. Lazy coders. So, for this problem, I can say: **SOLVED!**. Thx all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I am having is exactly that - get the cross compiler to see the target environment and not the build's.

Mounting the Rpi in a subdirectory is also something I'm working on past days, I found a description for an OsX-host, but as I only have Windows-computers I made some workarounds to get the RPi1 booting on an NFS-share of a Trusty-virtual machine instead of the SD-card:
https://github.com/rmast/rpi-build-and-boot

Comment: My next experiment will be using distcc from the pi-1 to distribute the cc-commands to the Ubuntu-virtual machine. That way I hope not to be dependent on well written cross-compilable code. This project takes me more than a native build with some gstreamer.sh from git, but I'm also learning, and indeed it would be neat to have a faster build-method.